# If $0<c<1$ then $c^n \leq c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I make an exercise in my book of analysis and I am stuck. Can somebody check, how can I solve it?

Exercise: the part (a) if $c>1$, then $c^n \geq c \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb N$

$\textbf{Solution}:$ let $x:=c-1>0$ and use Bernoulli’s Inequality then.

$(1+x)^n \geq 1+xn$

$(1+c-1)^n\geq 1+xn$

$c^n\geq 1+xn\geq 1+x=1+c-1=c.$ $\blacksquare$

the part (b) ( I have a problem here )

if $0<c<1$, then $c^n \leq c\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb N$. The tipp was $b:=\frac{1}{c}$ and use the part a. So I began:

$0<c<1 \iff 0<1<\frac{1}{c}=b$, so $x:=b-1>0$

$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$

$(1+b-1)^n \geq 1+nx$

$b^n \geq 1+nx \geq 1+x=1-b+1=b$ so I got

$b^n \geq b$ or $(\frac{1}{c})^n \geq \frac{1}{c}$, its
obviously what I need, but how can I show that this
expression is
equivalent to $c^n \leq c$. I am stuck here, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c = a/b$ where $0 < a < b$. This means that we are proving $(a/b)^n < a/b$. Note that $a < b$. Then, we'll have $a^{n-1} < b^{n-1}$ which we can get using the fact that if $x < y$ and $u < v$, then $ux < vy$. Clearly, $ab = ab$, which means $a^{n-1}\cdot ab < b^{n-1}\cdot ab$. By dividing both sides by $ab^n$, we get $a^n / b^n < a/b \implies (a/b)^n < a/b$.

Comment: Also, since $0 < c < 1$, you can't get $c^n = c$.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R$ is an ordered field. Then, if $a,b\in(0,1)$ we get $0<ab<a$ and $0<ab<b$. In words, if you multiply two positive numbers lesser than $1$, the result is lesser than both of them. So $\{c^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence in $(0,1)$ for $0<c<1$.